# Pytest Import Error when trying to import my class

Tags: python-3.x, import, pytest

so im making a basic calculator. For the sake of simplicity lets assume the whole code is

```
import math

class Calculator:

  def __init__(self):
    self.answer = 0.00


  def addition(self,num1,num2):
    self.answer = num1 + num2
    return self.answer
```

The file above is calculator.py

My Pytest file is called test_calculator.py and has the following code:

```
import pytest
from calculator import Calculator


def test_answer_init(calculator):
  calculator = Calculator()
  assert calculator.answer == 0.00
```

However, when i run the test i get the following error:

```
___ ERROR collecting test/test_calculator.py _________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/Jacob/Desktop/Python/test/test_calculator.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test/test_calculator.py:2: in <module>
    from calculator import Calculator
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calculator'
```

Could someone pleaw tell me the proper way to import my class

Comment: Can you tell us where theses files are located one relative to the other?

Comment: sure so my directory looks like this:
├── calculator.py
│   
│ ── __init__.py    
│     
├── test_calculator.py

Comment: not sure if you can see it peroperly but all three files are in the same folder and directory

Comment: No it doesn't display correctly in a comment. Can you modify your question to include that information?

Comment: Are you running the python interpreter from that directory? Because it will first search for modules in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing an empty `__init__.py` in your folder, which is needed to designate it as a Python package, and therefore be able to import modules from it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384 for more details.

And you should change `test_calculator.py` to:

```py
import pytest
from .calculator import Calculator


def test_answer_init():
  calculator = Calculator()
  assert calculator.answer == 0.00
```

Comment: no i have that file, this is my directory
├── calculator.py
│   
│ ── __init__.py    
│     
├── test_calculator.py

Comment: not sure if you can see it peroperly but all three files are in the same folder and directory

Comment: I updated the solution. Use the newer ``test_calculator.py`` that I modified.